# Updating a model with a keyup event in Backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am trying to update a model on every keyup event. The model's attributes will be used in the template. So they should be defined before page load. I have defined them `null`. But when something is typed I cannot read them updated from the console.

What is the proper way to do this? What is my missing point?

loginview fragment:

```
events: {
            'keyup input' : 'updateModel',
            'click #loginbutton' : 'login',
            'click #renderregisterbutton' : 'render_register',
        },
        updateModel: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var elm = e.target;
            FormsDataModelInst[ elm.id ] = $( elm ).val();
            this.model.set( FormsDataModelInst );
            console.log( "1-FormsDataModelInst:" + JSON.stringify( FormsDataModelInst.attributes ) );
            console.log( "2-this.model.set(...):" + JSON.stringify(this.model.attributes) );
            console.log( e );
            console.log( e.target );
            console.log( elm );
            console.log( elm.id );
            console.log( $( elm ).val() );              
        },
```

formsdatamodel:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone) {
        var FormsDataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: null,

            defaults: {
                username: null,
                phone: null,
                email: null,
            },
        });

        return new FormsDataModel();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Line should be used

```
        FormsDataModelInst.set( elm.id, $( elm ).val() );
```

instead of the line

```
        FormsDataModelInst[ elm.id ] = $( elm ).val();
```

This solves the problem. Using backbone's utilitess like set() as just the other models are set and saved etc. FormsDataModelInst's model is a Backbone model also.